# Image Cache only clears when clearing my browser cache

Tags: 7, caching, media

When I update my image style (for example adding a water mark overlay) the only way I can see the change is if I clear my browser cache. I am using the [ImageCache Actions](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) module.

I downloaded a fresh copy of Drupal and installed the Imagecahce Actions module and the problem doesn't happen on that site. It updates without requiring me to clear my browser cache.

Anyone have an idea what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Related issue => https://www.drupal.org/node/2424695

Answer (score 2):

Drupal some times uses cache in Images for better user performance.

if you want to view the image after the update or change you can use this code

```
<?php
 //get the image fiels
 if (isset($data->field_field_profile_pic) && !empty($data->field_field_profile_pic[0]['rendered']['#item']['uri'])) {
        $Logo = file_create_url($data->field_field_profile_pic[0]['rendered']['#item']['uri']);
 }

?>
//print the image tag
<a href="#"><img  src='<?php print $Logo.'?'.time();?>' alt=''></a>
```

Here the main code here is appending time stamp after your image as query string so **time()** will append the image tag with latest timestamp which will get the latest image from your server.

will reduce your burden from clearing your cache every time.

this is a quick fix we used in our project.